# Hybridauth Facebook display setting not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, hybridauth

In my website, I have integrated HybidAuth for Facebook Login authentication. I have installed HybridAuth using composer and integrated all required codes as per the document. The login authentication is working and I'm getting the response too. But now it is redirecting to facebook login page in full screen, to overcome this they have a display setting which includes these different settings "page, popup, iframe, touch or wap".

In this, "page" is the default. When I change it to "popup" or "iframe" it is not working.

My Reference Document: https://hybridauth.github.io/hybridauth/userguide/IDProvider_info_Facebook.html

My Code sample:

```
$configArray = array(
   "base_url" => "<< my base url >>",
       "providers" => array (
       "Facebook" => array (
           "enabled" => true, 
           "keys" => array ( "id" => "<< my app ID >>", "secret" => "<< my app secret key >>" ),
           "scope" => ['email', 'user_birthday', 'user_hometown'],  
           "display" => "popup"
       )
   )
);
```

I have installed the latest version and also included required files in my program. I need some help to find a solution to this issue, so I can have the login screen in a pop-up or in an iframe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `display` parameter does not change _how_ the login dialog is opened (same window per redirect, popup), it only advises Facebook to format the content in a way that is suitable for display under those different conditions.

Comment: Hi, @CBroe , can you please tell me where to change the display format in facebook app settings.

Comment: That is not an app setting; it simply depends on how your app calls the login dialog. You’d have to check with hybridauth docs, if they have a popup version implemented somehow, of if they just support the redirect flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also posted this question in Github and received the answer for this, Please check this link https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/issues/832

The display option is set to be not applicable in the Hybrid Auth implementation. This option can be used only when we use Facebook SDK for JavaScript.

SO the author removed the Display setting from the documentation and updated the document with this setting.

Thanks for all your answers and helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your html button leads to calling hybridauth decides how large the popup window is.
[check the tutorial here](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/link/html-link-new-window.htm)